# Мир - он непрост или не прост?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, частица-не

Все мы с детства помним строки песни "Мир не прост, совсем не прост...".
Но вот сегодня, когда я попытался процитировать эту строку в документе Google Docs, система редактирования услужливо предложила мне исправить ее на "Мир непрост, совсем непрост".
Поиск в Яндексе показал, что половина цитирующих эту песню утверждает, что мир не прост, а вторая половина уверена: он непрост.
Все грамматические комментарии в основном описывают форуму "непросто" и, возможно, не учитывают какой-то нюанс, касающийся именно формы "непрост".
Так каков он, наш мир?
Он непрост или совсем не прост?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Мир не прост, совсем не прост.* Отрицание чувствуется, явное предпочтение следует отдать раздельному написанию. Да тут еще и "совсем не" в значении "вовсе не".

Может быть, такой пример поможет:

*Он человек не простой* (принадлежит к какой-либо элите).

*Он человек непростой* (человек со сложным характером).

Comment: Да, в этом есть логика. Спасибо! Скажите, а как Вы считаете, возможно ли в данном контексте сразу два варианта написания в одном предложении: "Мир не прост, совсем непрост"?

Comment: Вот уж это нет.

Answer (score 3):

*Не* пишется слитно, если *совсем" употреблено в значении *очень*.
*Не* пишется раздельно, если *совсем не* употреблено в значении *отнюдь не*. 
(См: [Не с прилагательными и причастиями](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-00000000d8573f987cea4c65181925c6))

Думаю, в тексте песни все корректно: не подумайте, что мир прост,  он "не прост, а сложен" (отрицание), он "отнюдь не прост".

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Очень полезное дополнение. К сожалению, у меня недостаточно рейтинга, чтобы поставить Вам vote-up, иначе бы обязательно это сделал.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что здесь возможны **обе формы**, отрицательная и утвердительная.

Утверждение: Мир непрост (сложен), совсем (весьма) непрост...

Пример: Но рыцарский мир, как известно, весьма непрост. [Ю. И. Андреева. Многоточие сборки (2009)]

Comment: Я думал об этом, но "совсем непрост"  в значении "очень непрост" показалось мне настолько просторечным, что я этот вариант отбросил. Не к лицу такое Леониду Дербенёву.